# Do I need to mention the Poland stay back refusal in UK visa application?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications

I've been in poland for four years and completed my education. Applied for stayback because of the delay in getting the certificate and get apostile. Unfortunately, stay back visa was refused and I returned back to india.

Now planning to do masters in UK. I'm seriouly confused that do I have to mention this refusal in the UK application?

Comment: What is confusing about it? If the application asks about prior refusals you must disclose it.

Comment: Do I have to submit the decision letter? I just  know the decision was negative but didn't receive the letter and the reason.

Comment: Does the UK question direct you to attach the refusal letter?

Comment: There was no questions but the application asking for reason.As I mentioned before I don't know the reason for the refusal.

Comment: Then say you did not receive a refusal letter, and do not know the reason.

Comment: How do you know the visa was refused, if there was no letter, and no reason?

Comment: i sent an email asking for the decision. I got the reply say decision was issue and the letter was sent almost a month before.But I didn't receive any letter

Comment: Have you asked that a replacement letter be provided?

Comment: Yes, But no reply at all.

Comment: I just left the country the three days later after I got to know my stayback was refused.

Comment: As @WeatherVane asked: how do you know the application was refused?  What did the email actually say? (Your statement "...the decision was issue..." is not understandable and does not answer this concern, as your words "the decision" doesn't say _what decision was made_.) Add the actual email text into your question by using the "edit" button; do not include your personal or identifying information.